# How would one integrate ag-grid into MDriven Turnkey?

Tags: mdriven

I'm interested in using MDriven Turnkey, but I have to have a powerful full-featured data grid. The best grid that I have found is https://www.ag-grid.com/

1. How would I go about integrating this into Turnkey? Is it even
   possible?
2. Would this negate the advantages of data management and Viewmodels etc built into the MDriven Designer?
3. Has anyone had any experience of doing this?
4. Is there any information anywhere on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use any front end javascript based control with MDriven Turnkey.

And yes - depending on how much work you put into making your integration generic or not you loose some advantages for the screens that depend on the new control.

If we focus on the basic - just make it show up and show data:

1. Use EXT_Components in MDriven as [described here](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/EXT_Components)
2. Start by doing a non generic control with hard coded columns and hard coded knowledge of what data to use (will be unique for 1 screen or use case)
3. You can at any time see what data you have accessible in the page by appending /debug to url of a Turnkey screen as [described here](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Development_info_in_runtime)
4. If you later on want to make a generic control, i.e. a control that reads meta data from Turnkey and use that meta data to create columns as designed in the ViewModel it is more complex but absolutely doable since screen meta data is available as [described here](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/ViewMeta)

Comment: Would I use the Javascript or the Angular version of ag-grid?

Comment: I am not sure what will be easiest. If you want the list of rows to change when new objects are created - you will need to observe the list objects - and this is handled by Angular - I guess the angular 1.x version is the best option